# deny change nickname permission

Tags: discord.js

```js
message.guild.createRole({
   name:  message.member.user.tag,
    color: 'RANDOM',
    deny: ['CHANGE_NICKNAME'],
})
```

It seems the deny parameter for `createRole()` is not working & will not deny the change nickname permission, I tried multiple variations but it seems to want to enable it by default. I've even included the value of `CHANGE_NICKNAME` which is: `0x04000000` but this does not want to seem to take effect, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `deny` is not a parameter in [`RoleData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/typedef/RoleData), you need to use the `permissions` parameter and then pass the denied permissions:

```js
message.guild.createRole({
    name:  message.member.user.tag,
    color: 'RANDOM',
    permissions: [{
      deny: ['CHANGE_NICKNAME']
    }]
})
```

Comment: Apparently the : next to deny, is a unexpected token?